# jquery class selector only registering events on first element of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

im currently working on a form field highlighter in jquery and so far it works except it only works on the first line of the form and the rest of the fields do not register my focus events so that i may apply focus formatting 
 i am currently using the following jquery code

```
    var debug = false;




    $(function(){

        $(".email-form tbody:last").AddFormLineToTable();

        $("#do-add-row").click(function () {

            if(debug)
            {
                alert("serialize click eventhandler fired");
            }

            $(".email-form tbody:last").AddFormLineToTable();
        });



        $(".does-focus-highlight").focusin(function(e){

            $(e.target).addClass("focus-highlight");
            if(debug){alert('field did focus');}
        });
        $(".does-focus-highlight").focusout(function(e){
            $(e.target).removeClass("focus-highlight");
            if(debug){alert('field did blur');}

        });


        $("#do-serialize").click(function(){
          if(debug)
          {
              alert("serialize click eventhandler fired");
          }
           var jsn = $("#contact-form").serializeArray();
        $("#serialize-target").val(JSON.stringify(jsn,null,2));



        });



    });
```

is there something im missing to catch these additional events 
the form fields that are not firing are being generated dunamically as well if that makes a difference as well 
which are being generated as follows

```
    var lineCount = 0;

jQuery.fn.AddFormLineToTable = function() {
    var o = $(this[0]);
    o.append('<tr id="contact-'+lineCount+'">' +
        '<td>Name: <input class="does-focus-highlight" id="contact-name-'+lineCount+'" name="contact-name-'+lineCount+'" type="text" required="required" /></td>' +
        '<td>Email: <input class="does-focus-highlight" id="contact-email-'+lineCount+'" name="contact-email-'+lineCount+'" type="email" required="required" /></td>' +
        '</tr>');

    lineCount++;
};
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle.net for that?

Comment: Why do you select an empty Objext (`$(this[0])`), but then apply a jQuery-method (`append`)?

Comment: $(this[0]) gets the first object in the selector

Comment: if there is a cleaner way to get this let me know please note this is being registered as a plugin

Comment: You could go with `.first()` - "Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set". It's the same as what you've got - functionally. The solution to your main problem is given below. You are creating additional rows after you've assigned the event listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.click()` binds events only to elements that are existing at the time of calling `.click()`. If you want the events to be handled for elements that are created later on, use `.on()` or `.live()`, depending on the version of jQuery you are using. Read the very helpful info [here](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).